# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net

I am not the best in C# as I currently still learning as I go! However, I got stuck on assigning parsed JSON values from an asset file.

The parsing works fine, and I can locate a path. However, the value is retrieved as an object, and I cannot convert it into an integer which is the current JSON value.

How would I go about retrieving the JSON value in the correct format? Either being string or int.

I've tried `Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value)` AND `(int) reader.Value` as you can see below.

But I receive the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'`

Also, I've tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.Value)`

Which gives two errors:

- `The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found`
- `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object to 'string'`

**Note:** CustomerVolumes() is just a getter/setter mapping class of complete JSON response. Some values are strings or integers. Nothing special!

**Using:** http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm

And **also** used: http://json2csharp.com to create ***CustomerVolumes*** class

```
public class DashboardActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Dashboard);

        string  jsonResponse      = ReadFile();
        var     CustomerVolumes   = new CustomerVolumes();

        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(@jsonResponse));

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Value != null)
            {
                if (reader.Path.Equals("customers.id.cycles.yyyy_mm.scopes.mms.volume") && !reader.Value.Equals("volume"))
                {
                    CustomerVolumes.customers.id.cycles.yyyy_mm.scopes.mms.volume = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                }

                if (reader.Path.Equals("customers.id.cycles.yyyy_mm.scopes.gprs.volume") && !reader.Value.Equals("volume"))
                {
                    CustomerVolumes.customers.id.cycles.yyyy_mm.scopes.gprs.volume = (int) reader.Value;
                }
        }
    }

    private string ReadFile()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(JSON_FILE));
        string text     = sr.ReadToEnd();
                          sr.Close();

        return text;
    }
}

public class Mms
{
    public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class Gprs
{
    public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class Voice
{
    public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class Sms
{
    public int volume { get; set; }
}

public class Scopes
{
    public Mms mms { get; set; }
    public Gprs gprs { get; set; }
    public Voice voice { get; set; }
    public Sms sms { get; set; }
}

public class YyyyMm
{
    public Scopes scopes { get; set; }
}

public class Cycles
{
    public YyyyMm yyyy_mm { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public Cycles cycles { get; set; }
}

public class Customers
{
    public Id id { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerVolumes
{
    public Customers customers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try : Int32.Parse(<stringValue>) ?

Comment: Yes. but I receive (local variable) JsonTextReader reader - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: What is the value of `Reader.Value` when viewed through debug?

Comment: isn't `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>( string )` available to read the full text to a specified class?

Comment: @vipersassassin it's some type of number 11 (as an example). I cannot tell if it's an integer, object, or string. But according to the documentations it's an 'object'.

Comment: @Icepickle, I've updated my question with your suggestion! Unless, I am doing it incorrectly..

Comment: `<T>` is intended to be the type. either a class that it can deserialize into or a standard type like string. This would be similar to when you type `List<string>` instead of `List<T>`

Comment: Yeah, you are doing it wrong, you are reading the text, there is no reason for the JsonReader, you just need to convert your full text...

Comment: @Icepickle can you provide an example?

Comment: Yeah, would this help you out? https://dotnetfiddle.net/QO4ZrZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use the JsonReader in your case as you have a generated object for your full JsonResponse called `CustomerVolumes`

To use this in your method, just use:

```
var customerVolumes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerVolumes>( jsonResponse );
```

This will give you a new instance of `CustomerVolumes` with all values correctly filled in.

No need to parse the full object and the correct path.

As an example, you can check out this [.netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QO4ZrZ) which takes a json object and converts it in a C# class.

As I don't have any of the data you are working with, this is a small example program to show how it could work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static string fakeJsonString = 
        @"{ ""text"": ""This is a text"", ""intValue"": 10, ""dictionary"": { ""key"": ""value"" }, ""array"": [ 10, 20, 30 ] }";


    internal class FakeObject {
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get;set; }
        [JsonProperty("intValue")]
        public int IntValue { get;set; }
        [JsonProperty("dictionary")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get;set; }
        [JsonProperty("array")]
        public int[] IntArray { get;set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var fakeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FakeObject>( fakeJsonString );
        Console.WriteLine("Current value for text: "  + fakeObject.Text);
        Console.WriteLine("Current value for intValue: "  + fakeObject.IntValue);
        Console.WriteLine("Current value for Dictionary: "  + string.Join( ",", fakeObject.Dictionary.Select(kvp => "\"" + kvp.Key + "\": \"" + kvp.Value + "\"" ) ) );
        Console.WriteLine("Current value for IntArray: "  + string.Join( ",", fakeObject.IntArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confuse about this! Keep in mind that I am not proficient in C#. I implemented: var fakeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerVolumes>(@jsonResponse);
Console.WriteLine(fakeObject.customers.id.cycles.yyyy_mm.scopes.gprs.volume); and received: System.NullReferenceExceipt: object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Also, id and yyyy_mmm will also always be different integer values. For now, I am testing the implement from an asset json file. So attempting to match and map it with an object class isn't 100% efficient

Comment: @tfont No problem, please note that I also mentioned that this is hard as I don't know how your Json data looks like or how CustomerVolumes is implemented. If you could give some sample data and the implementation of CustomerVolumes, it would make it a lot easier.

Comment: @tfont, please add it to your question, in comments it's so sucky to read ;)

Comment: added the classes to my question :]

Comment: @tfont Great, just add the JsonData as well still please :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131078/discussion-between-icepickle-and-tfont).

Comment: @tfont Just join me in the chat, maybe we can get through this quickly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with what you are trying to do, but just a guess worth trying. [On this website](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Value.htm) it shows the JsonReader.Value property returning an Object rather than a string. Perhaps try explicitly doing a reader.value.tostring() and converting that to an integer. If the types are correct I can't see why your code isn't working.

As for the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.Value)` make sure that you are exchanging the T for a String like:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(reader.Value)
```

Good luck!

Edit:

Not familiar with what you are trying to do, but just a guess worth trying. [On this website](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Value.htm) it shows the JsonReader.Value property returning an Object rather than a string. Perhaps try explicitly doing a reader.value.tostring() and converting that to an integer. If the types are correct I can't see why your code isn't working.

As for the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.Value)` make sure that you are exchanging the T for a String like:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(reader.Value)
```

Good luck!

Edit:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Value != null)
    {
        string rVal = (string)reader.Value
        if (reader.Path.Equals("customers.id.cycles.yyyy_mm.scopes.mms.volume") && !(rVal.toUpper() == "VOLUME"))
        {
            CustomerVolumes.customers.id.cycles.yyyy_mm.scopes.mms.volume = Convert.ToInt32(rVal);
        }
}
```

what happens when you try that?

Comment: Thanks! Still playing around with this DeserializeObject, but seeming to get nowhere! I tried string str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String>(reader.Value); and received" Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: I used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Int32>(reader.Value.ToString()) which was sneaky but then I received 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: He has a generated object meant for his full Json string, there is no need to use the reader, he can simple convert the JsonResponse to CustomerVolumes class that was generated as well

Comment: @Icepickle I just read your jfiddle comment above, disregard. Thanks!

Comment: @Rhurac I received: System.InvalidCastException: Specific cast is not valid.

Comment: @tfont Icepickle has the answer sorry for the confusion.